# Prove that this set is a convex cone

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-cone

> Let $$S := \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x^T Q x \leq (a^Tx)^2,  a^T x \geq0 \right\}$$ where $Q \in \mathbb{S}_{++}^n$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $S$ is a convex cone.

---

I am aware that for a set to be a convex cone, the following should hold:-

1. $x,y \in S$ $\implies$ $x+y \in S$
2. $x\in S$ and $\theta \geq 0$ $\implies$ $\theta x \in S$

I attempted to use $x,y \in S$ to get $x+y \in S$ but so far I have been unsuccessful. The squared term on the R.H.S is throwing me off. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

EDIT: I have attempted the following working. Kindly verify if this is correct

$(x+y)^TQ(x+y)=x^TQx+x^TQy+y^TQx+y^TQy \  $ $ \leq \ (a^Tx)^2+(a^Ty)^2+2x^TQy$

$\leq \ (a^Tx)^2+(a^Ty)^2+2a^Tx^TQy$

$\leq (a^T(x+y))^2$

I'm not sure about the second last step. Thanks in advance

EDIT 2:

I believe that the following proof should suffice. Kindly let me know if any errors are found and of any alternate proof that may exist. Thank you.

First I will show that S is convex.

A set S is convex if for $\alpha , \beta \in [0,1]$ , $\alpha + \beta =1$ and $x,y\in S$, we have $\alpha x + \beta y \in S$
If $x \in S$ then $x^TQx \leq (a^Tx)^2$ and $a^Tx \geq 0$

Similarly, if  $y \in S$ then $y^TQy \leq (a^Ty)^2$ and $a^Ty \geq 0$

Then, $\alpha x + \beta y \in S \implies (\alpha x + \beta y)^T Q (\alpha x + \beta y) \leq (a^T(\alpha x + \beta y))^2$

Lets focus on the LHS of this inequality.

$(\alpha x + \beta y)^T Q (\alpha x + \beta y) = \alpha^2 x^TQx + \beta y^TQy + 2\alpha \beta x^TQy$

Let's attempt to separate $x$ and $y$ from $x^TQy$

$x^TQy = x^T Q^{1/2} Q^{1/2} y = (Q^{1/2}x)^T(Q^{1/2}y) \ \ $ (since $Q \in S_{++}^n$)

$(Q^{1/2}x)^T(Q^{1/2}y) \leq ||Q^{1/2}x|| \cdot ||Q^{1/2}y|| \ \ $ (Cauchy Schwartz Inequality)

$||Q^{1/2}x|| \cdot ||Q^{1/2}y|| = \sqrt{\langle Q^{1/2}x, Q^{1/2}x \rangle} \sqrt{\langle Q^{1/2}y, Q^{1/2}y \rangle} = \sqrt{x^TQx} \cdot \sqrt{y^TQy}$

By the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean Inequality, we know that $\sqrt{ab} \leq \frac{(a+b)}{2}$ and $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$ for non-negative reals.

Hence,

$\sqrt{x^TQx} \cdot \sqrt{y^TQy} \leq \frac{1}{2} (x^TQx + y^TQy)$

$\implies \alpha^2 x^TQx + \beta y^TQy + 2 \alpha \beta x^TQy \leq \alpha^2 x^TQx + \beta y^TQy + \alpha \beta (x^TQx + y^TQy)$

Let $\beta = 1 - \alpha$

$\implies \alpha^2 x^TQx + (1-\alpha)^2y^TQy + \alpha (1- \alpha) (x^TQx + y^TQy) $

$= \alpha x^T Q x + (1-\alpha)y^TQy$

$\implies (\alpha x + \beta y)^T Q (\alpha x + \beta y) \leq \alpha x^T Q x + (1- \alpha) y^TQy$

$\leq \alpha (a^Tx)^2 + (1 - \alpha)(a^Ty)^2$

$\leq \alpha (a^Tx)^2 + (1 - \alpha)(a^Ty)^2 + 2 \alpha \beta (a^Tx)(a^Ty)$

$= (a^T(\alpha x + \beta y))^2$

$\implies (\alpha x + \beta y)^T Q (\alpha x + \beta y) \leq (a^T(\alpha x + \beta y))^2 $

Which is what we required. Hence, S is convex.

For S to be a cone, let $\theta \geq 0$ and $x \in S$. Then, $S$ is a cone if $\theta x \in S$

$x \in S \implies x^TQx \leq (a^Tx)^2$

We know that $\theta^2 \geq 0$ so we can multiply on both sides without changing the inequality sign

$\theta ^2 x^TQx \leq \theta^2(a^Tx)^2$

$\theta x^T Q \theta x \leq (a^T \theta x)^2$

$\implies \theta x \in S$

Hence, $S$ is a cone.

Therefore, $S$ is a convex cone.

Comment: Have you tried rewriting as the sublevel set of a quadratic form?

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo Yes but I'm still stuck. Could you please elaborate a little further?

Comment: Try to rewrite as $x^\top M x \leq 0$, where $M$ is indefinite.

Comment: This is too long. Please break into sections. The problem, the background and motivation, some thoughts, several candidate solutions, etc. Use `### Section` to create a header.

Comment: The question is a part of exercises from Amir Beck's Introduction to Nonlinear Optimization. It is exercise 7.2.

Comment: Again, that information should be included in the question, not in the comment section. Write your question as you would write a short academic paper.

Comment: Again, try to rewrite the predicate as the difference between two PSD matrices.